# Office365 SSO from ASP.NET application with no Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, office365

We want to make a Single Sign On to Office365 from an ASP.NET web application that stores username and password in a database. We do not have Active Directory accounts for these users.

What I can read about SSO to office365 is that it only allows SSO with an on premise AD. But there should be some work arounds around this.

Anyone who can give me a pointer on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but difficult. We spent like a month to get it done.

What you have to do is to set up your own ws-federation security token service. You develop it with WIF. It should expose the exact metadatw and claims that ADFS2.0 does. This is one of the tricky parts as this is not documented anywhere and requires some reverse engineering on ADFS metadata.

When the sts is ready and functional, the O365 will not see a difference between your sts and thr ADFS and will happily authenticate users against your own sts. And the sts can use any user backstore you want.

Yet another problem is the way you automate O365 to create user accounts. This is simpler, as the powershell api is well documented and allows you to mimic the way the DirSync works so that you don't need DirSync and the AD.

This only scratches the surface and be prepared for a tough research. Any specific questions can be answered but I wouldn't expect a step-by-step tutorial from anyone. At least we haven't found anything and we did all by ourselves.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor
Nice to know that there at least is a way to accomplish it. We will build our own user account creation from the api. That is not my concern.

Comment: If you guys have specific questions, we can provide answers.

Comment: I would be really surprised if this works just out of the box. Although IndentityServer is a nice, custom STS, O365 is rather capricious when it comes to accepting claims from a custom STS. You should probably spend some time on a research to try to make both talk to each other.

Comment: Would it be possible to buy the solution from you?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is not of a production quality as it was a research project. The retail implementation was rescheduled for late 2013/early 2014.

Comment: How did you get the configuration data out of Office365?